# Excel VBA count cells containing value and record number in cell containing symbol

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure how to start this code and I am not very good at VBA. Basically I have 2 columns I am interested in. One column (column E) contains cells with the word Header. I want to count those from top to bottom and in a cell 1 row to the left I need to put the current count at the beginning of the text in that cell.

```
ROW | column D  | Column E 
1   |   AHU     | Header
2   |  random   | random
3   |   FCU     | Header
```

Comment: Almost litterally googling your questions results in a first hit bringing you back to SO http://goo.gl/oClkaz

Comment: Well that thread doesn't answer my question so thats why I didn't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need VBA, you could use `=COUNTIF($E$2:E2,"Header")`

If you are going to loop through the rows, you can use a counter like below:

```
Dim ct as Long
Dim i as Long
Dim iLastRow as Long

iLastRow = Range("E2", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count

For i = 2 to iLastRow
    If Range("E" & i).value="Header" then
         ct = ct + 1
         Range("D" & i).value = ct & "-" & Range("D" & i).value
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: This code looks like it would work but I cannot get it to do anything. I run the code and nothing happens. I place Header in column E then random letter in column D then execute the code and nothing happens. Not sure why?

Comment: I think Wyatt forgot to define `iLastRow`.  After the second `Dim` add this `iLastRow = Range("E2", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count`